# Android | Upload image with params

Tags: php, android, upload

I upload an image on my server with the following code, and it works. But I would to pass some params with the image, I've tried to pass "value" as "test", but doesn't work.

```
public int uploadFile(File selectedFile){
    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    String selectedFilePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

    int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
        //dialog.dismiss();
        return 0;
    }else {
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(ServerTools.SERVER+"profile/test.php");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            //PARAMS!!!
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"value\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("test" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();


            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                responseOutput.append(line);
            }
            br.close();

            Log.i("Test", "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode+ " -> "+responseOutput);

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return serverResponseCode;
}
```

My php server is simple:

```
<?php
$wp = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($wp,"test.jpg");
echo "value: ".$_POST["value"];
?>
```

But the Log.d prints: `Server Response is: OK: 200 -> value:`

How can I pass some parametres correcly?

Answer (score 0):

Part of my working code for file headers, just check/try if it´s working for you

```
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + jsonField + "\"; filename=\"" + q[jsonName] + "\"" + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + "application/json" + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);

outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```